# Special Symbols converted into question mark in OpenEdge

Tags: symbols, openedge, progress-4gl

i want to remove some special symbols from input string but not question marks. when i do so, instead of removing special symbol , it shows question marks? please help.

Comment: What symbols you want to remove? You are seeing question marks in place of special characters due to some bad codepage conversions. Check your server and client codepages. Make sure that they are compatible/same.

Comment: You need to specify what you have done already, and which special characters you are talking about. This question has nowhere enough detail to begin trying to help.

Comment: If you are having trouble in identifying code pages, try starting your client with some generic code page like "UTF-8". Use "-cpinternal UTF-8" startup parameter when you start the client.

Comment: Which OS? What's your SESSION:CPINTERNAL value?

Comment: OS : Windows 7 , SESSION:CPINTERNAL  : ISO8859-1

Comment: Are you sure the values are really changed to "?"? It could just be that those values cant be displayd. Export the values to a file and open it in an editor that supports utf-8 (no, not notepad).